# gcc optimization flag break code

Tags: c++, pointers, optimization, gcc

This code works fine when no optimization flag are set:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main(){
  float *ptr = ({float var[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}; var;});
  float *ptr1 = ({float var[10]; for(int i_=0;i_<10;i_++)var[i_]=i_+1; var;});
  float *ptr2 = ({float var[10]; var[4]=5; var;});
  printf("\n value = %f %f %f",ptr[4],ptr1[4],ptr2[4]);
}
```

It returns `5 5 5` as expected.
But when optimization flag are set, it returns `5 0 5`.

`ptr1` have problem something related to the loop. Why?
Maybe its a bug?

I'm using the latest, 4.8.0, tested x64, x86 as well other builds. All same behaviour.

Comment: Looks like pointers to expired temporaries.

Comment: Yup, reeks of undefined behaviour. I didn't know this was legal, thoguh, so thanks.

Comment: @chris it's a GNU language extension

Comment: it is a bug, in your code. you cannot return a pointer of a stack object and use it outside the scope.

Comment: @Cubbi, Oh, thanks. I didn't realize `-pedantic` is off by default on Coliru.

Answer (score 8):

You're using a GNU language extension, so let's look at the [GNU documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html):

> In a statement expression, any temporaries created within a statement are destroyed at that statement's end.

`var` is destroyed every time, and a pointer to its first element (which is what's returned by the expressions) is not safe to dereference.

Answer (score 2):

The values pointed to by var are allocated on the stack. However, var's scope is the brackets that it is contained within. Setting a pointer to var results in undefined behaviour. As you have seen, in most cases the values in the stack have not changed by the time you print them. However, this can change with different optimization settings. This is not a bug. It is just the nature of undefined behaviour.

Comment: So if I want defined behavior have to allocate it on heap. But then I have always to delete it. I thought that I could pass references, just like in functions, but it seems that It deletes on the stack where created. Strange dow, I think it should not be undefined behaviour, as the returning are indeed a reference to &var[0]

Comment: Here's the issue. The memory still exists. Chances are that nothing has happened to the memory you are pointing to. When the array was in scope, it was simply somewhere back in the stack. The stack contains a mix of variables and pointers to locations in the program. When something goes out of scope, all the variables that were pushed onto the stack get popped off. As new values get pushed onto the stack, the values quickly become overwritten.

Comment: And there is no way to dont let pop a choosed one? I mean, move from one stack to another, without the heap solution. Just like we do in functions. Of course the standard deletes on the stack where was created, but a move isnt possible?

Comment: The stack is basically just a really big array. When you call a function, the current program state written to the top of the stack. The function can then write values to the stack. When it is done it moves the top of the stack back and the rest of the code executes. Although your values have not changed, they cannot be protected. Eventually, the stack will grow again and they will be overwritten. What you can do is declare each of the arrays earlier in the program. That will allow you to access them later while they are still in scope.